# Laravel App not running on xampp or live server but works well on php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, .htaccess, xampp

My laravel app does not work on xampp or a live server but it works fine on the link provided by PHP artisan serve. Whenever I run this app on xampp it returns 404 error. I have other laravel apps also which work fine on xampp but this one.
I am unable to find any solution to it that why my laravel is not running on a hosted server or xampp. I have tried all the solutions found in related questions but did not find any of those useful.

- I have tried running the app after changing my existing .htaccess
  file in the root folder.
- I have tried running the app after changing .htaccess file in public
  folder.
- I have tried running the app after deleting both and one of them.
- I have tried installing and updating the dependencies again using
  composer.

What should I do to make it running?

What I see when I try to run it through xampp is the errors, but the folder structure that always occurs when one runs a web app through it.

Right now, I have a single htaccess file which is in my root folder. Below is the code of it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Code of my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.6",
        "jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^3.6",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.1",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/dusk"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Code of my package.json file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

Code of my server.php file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Code of my index.php file in public folder:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Error I am getting when I run the App on xampp

[image]

Laravel App current folder structure

[image]

Comment: You need to edit the apache config, to point `DocumentRoot` to `laravel_root/public`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran into this problem too. I've done some research and the only way I found possible to run Laravel on xampp was the following:

1. In the parent folder of the laravel setup, I created a folder called "laravel" and moved **everything** inside of it.
2. I went in laravel/public and took every file out of it, and I put it in the parent directory, resulting in the following folder structure: (in my htdocs)

> ```
> |-.htaccess  
> |-favicon.ico  
> |-index.php  
> |-robots.txt  
> |-web.config   
> \---laravel
> ```

3. Go in index.php and change the code lines where it's loading files to load files from the new path instead (for example):

> ```
> if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/laravel/storage/framework/maintenance.php'))   
> {  
>     require __DIR__.'/laravel/storage/framework/maintenance.php';  
> }
> ```

4. Start apache and check localhost and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it literally solved my problem.
After that, just to figure out what the actual problem could be, I changed back my whole project as it was before when I asked this question and then changed the name of my app folder, and doing so also solved this issue.

Comment: You're welcome, man! Do note, however, that while this solution works like this, you won't be able to start Laravel up with 'php artisan serve' anymore since the public folder is moved out.