# Laravel form submit does not direct to route when used in xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am very new to Laravel so having quite a issues. I have a file of extension blade.php with form which directs to web.php having post route

Form html:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    
                    <!-- value Part -->
                    

                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="thing" id="title">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-danger" value="Upload">
                    </form>
```

Route in web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('showForm');
});

Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request) {
    $name=$request->file("thing")->getClientOriginalName();

    Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("",$request->file("thing"),$name);
    $url=Storage::disk('google')->url($name);
    DB::insert('insert into books (Title, Url) values (?,?)', [$name,$url]);
})->name("upload");
```

When used with php artisan serve, it works fine but when have to use in xampp it doesn't work. Clicking on the upload button redirect to localhost/uploads with error.
File not found. Requested url was not found on the server.

Initially, the html code is in localhost/webdev/example-app

I have tried
•Renaming server.php to index.php
•Moving .htaccess to root directory

•https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824607/laravel-app-not-running-on-xampp-or-live-server-but-works-well-on-php-artisan-se
Followed this link

•Changing the form action field as

```
<form action="webdev/example-app/laravel/webdev.php/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And in route post instead of /upload, giving the same path

Changing this path to various styles also

•edit a file called httpd.conf to change DocumentRoot to
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/webdev/example-app"

The last step did work and I could redirect to route and upload my files. It is possibly because when I click upload button then request is transferred to localhost/upload which is not the desired path but now because document root is the project folder so it becomes the correct path.

But now with this last step the issue is that doing this will directly run the html code on localhost
So now i am not able to open other folders and file present in htdocs folder in xampp

So how can I resolve my issue, that without artison serve, i could redirect to route in web.php and also i could open all folder in htdocs (which doesn't happen following the last step)

Comment: do not repost... I have already replied to your other duplicated question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run laravel on Xampp without Artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862260/how-to-run-laravel-on-xampp-without-artisan)

Comment: it does not resolve, that's why i posted

Comment: You don't have to re post the question, I also added a new comment there so you can try. Do not repost as the duplicates will get deleted.